# How to get duplicated keys from dictionary

Tags: dictionary, duplicates

I would like to get all duplicated keys from the dictionary. I know that dictionaries do not support duplicated keys, but maybe is it a workaround on it.

my_dict = {"key1":"value1", "key1":"value2", "key2":"value3", "key3":"value4", "key3":"value5", "key4": "value6"}

Desired output:
list_of_keys = ("key1", "key3")

I tried a lot of ideas which I found on Stackoverflow, but so far unsuccessfully.

Comment: dictionaries are hash tables, it is not possible to have duplicates keys in them

Comment: If you try to generate that dictionary, `"key1":"value1"` will be overwritten by `"value2"`. So the real question - is what are you really trying to do, because that dictionary will not exist in that format after creation. Where are the keys and values coming from?

Comment: This is necessary to check if provided parameters (keys) by user in the request body (REST API) are not duplicated. I was able to do it with query parameters using request. args. getlist () method (Flask API).